# Set a row to follow my cursor anywhere in Calc

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc

How do I make a whole row follow wherever I am in the Calc document when I scroll down/up?

I'm looking for something that keeps a row from moving, or to make it stay put.

This is so that when I want to see other rows, this one locked row will stay in place and allow me to refer back to it on screen without having to scroll all the way back up to the top of the document.

Normal:

[image]

Scrolled down:

[image]

Further scrolled down:

[image]

You can see the row with the yellow background, (CD-Nr.|Title|Genre|Lang|CD) is following me as I scroll down.

How is this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're talking about ["Freezing a Row"](http://www.openofficetips.com/blog/archives/2004/09/freezing_row_co.html)

[image]

more details in [The Open Office Wiki](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Getting_Started/Freezing_rows_and_columns)

Comment: not working for me here.

Comment: It's freeze in Excel and as the OpenOffice UI is based on Microsoft Office it should be the same.

Comment: @StampedeXV I also had trouble using 'Freeze' at first. Remember to select a cell, not a whole row, to the right of (in the case of column) or directly below (in the case of a row) the area you want to freeze. Look closely to how it's being done in the picture.

Comment: ah, problem was with "one below" and only selecting the cell. Always trying to fixate a whole line/column. Thank you - did not now that also.

Comment: cheers! That did it! Much appreciated!